Loop tools Bridge not joining three joined circles with the same vertex count in Blender 4.2
Trying to bridge three identical vert count circles, using loop tools bridge, however, instead of bridging them, it just bridges two.
Joined all three, middle one last to join, tried different ways of joining, still wont bridge them. What am I doing wrong?


Admittedly, it is a bit confusing that when you hover your mouse over the two tools, the Bridge tool and the Loft tool share the same tool tip: "Bridge two, or loft several, loops of vertices."

Nevertheless they are two different tools that only share the same settings in the tool options and if you change them for one, the changes apply to the other as well:

But as the tool tip clearly states, Bridge only connects two loops, for several you need Loft. However, as you can see in the follwoing example with 4 loops, Bridge can connect more than two as well, but only in pairs. So when you have three like your example, the third loop is missing another one to build a second pair.


Thank you Gordon - i shall hover more.

@PenelopeSaladfingers Glad I could help. Please read: What should I do when someone answers my question?
